# How to fix overlapping navbar dropdown on right side navbar using app.css of react js

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I got confuse on this app.css of built css of react js. why my navigation dropdown overlap on the right side. for the reference please see my uploaded image. currently I used react js and laravel for development. I don't find any solution for this. is there any one experience this same with me?

[image: Sample Image]

Html Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

we need to change css

```
#navbarSupportedContent {
    .navbar-nav {
        li.nav-item:last-child {
            .dropdown-menu {
                right: 0;
                left: auto;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `dropdown-menu-right` class in your `dropdown-menu` class. It will solve your problem.

> `<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">`